# How can I set CC and AR in Makefile that works for both Windows and Linux platforms?

Tags: linux, windows, makefile, cross-platform, gnu-make

My team member uses a Windows build environment and the Makefile has:

```
CC := $(ANDROID_NDK_HOME)/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc.exe
AR := $(ANDROID_NDK_HOME)/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ar.exe
```

Where the ANDROID_NDK_HOME is an environment variable that the user must set.

I want to use the same Makefile on my Ubuntu installation but want to change the Makefile such that both of us can use the same Makefile. Is that possible? In the interim, I made the following change which works.

```
CC := $(ANDROID_NDK_HOME)/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc
AR := $(ANDROID_NDK_HOME)/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ar
```

Basically, the change is "windows-x86" to linux-x86 and removed the .exe in name of binary itself.

Any tips/pointers appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can branch on some OS-specific environment variable. E.g.: `COMSPEC` is always set to non-empty value on Windows and *probably* not defined on other platforms.

```
ifneq ($(COMSPEC),)
  # Windows
  CC := $(ANDROID_NDK_HOME)/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc.exe
  AR := $(ANDROID_NDK_HOME)/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ar.exe
else
  # Not Windows
  CC := $(ANDROID_NDK_HOME)/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc
  AR := $(ANDROID_NDK_HOME)/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ar
endif
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexeySemenyuk. I decided to use ifeq($(OS),WindowsNt)

Comment: @guraaf, on my Win7 box value of `OS` environment variable is `Windows_NT`, not `WindowsNt`. May be this is just your typo error, or it is possible that value of `OS` environment variable on your box is indeed `WindowsNt`. Anyway this is a clear hint not to rely on particular value of the varible if possible. That is another pro argument to use `COMSPEC`.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. It was a typo. Yes, Windows_NT. But you are correct. I will switch to ComSpec.